# How to merge/join/combine 2 series in XOR manner while keeping conflicting values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, xor

I have the following dataframe, where '' is considered as empty:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: ['a', 'b', 'c']+ ['']*2, 2: ['']*2+ ['d','e', 'f']})
   1  2
0  a  '' 
1  b  '' 
2  c  d
3  '' e
4  '' f
```

How can I merge/join/combine (I don't know the correct term)  col2 into col1 so that I have:

```
   1  2
0  a ''  
1  b ''  
2  c  d
3  e '' 
4  f ''
```

or if I decide to merge col1 into col2:

```
   1  2
0 ''  a
1 ''  b
2  c  d
3 ''  e
4 ''  f
```

I would like to be able to decide in which col to merge and the other col should contain the conflict values.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the dataframe method `apply()`:

Sample data:

```
df
   1  2
0  a   
1  b   
2  c  d
3     e
4     f
```

Define arbitrary variables:

```
merge_to_column = 2
other_column = 1
```

Use apply:

```
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[other_column] if x[merge_to_column] == '' else x[merge_to_column], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
df
  1  2 output
0  a         a
1  b         b
2  c  d      d
3     e      e
4     f      f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the combine_first method for a vectorized (and simpler) version:

```
df[1].replace('', np.nan).combine_first(df[2])
```

results in:

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    e
4    f
```

You could also get both columns at once:

```
df.replace('', np.nan).combine_first(df.rename(columns={1: 2, 2: 1}))
```

results in:

```
   1  2
0  a  a
1  b  b
2  c  d
3  e  e
4  f  f
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def merge(col1, col2):
    for x in range(len(col1)):
        if col1[x] == '':
            col1[x] = col2[x]
            col2[x] = ''
```

This function will merge values from col2 into col1 where it finds quote marks, assuming both columns are the same size. You can handle different sizes as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .fillna():

```
df[1] = df[1].fillna(df[2])
```

then you take out the values from df[2] take collide:

```
df[2] = [None if r[1] == r[2] else r[2] for _, r in df.iterrows()]
```

output:

```
        1   2
   0    a   None
   1    b   None
   2    c   d
   3    e   None
   4    f   None
```

Note that instead of using '' for empty values, you have to use None in this case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: ['a', 'b', 'c']+[None]*2, 2: [None]*2+['d','e', 'f']})
```